# Does Neustar(quova) and Akamai Edgescape provide IP to country Database?

Tags: geolocation, ip, akamai, ip-geolocation, quova

I want to implement IP to the country solution in my code to customize content as per country of the user. Does Akamai Edgescape or Neustar(Quova) provide free/paid DB along with libraries to read them?

Answer (score 0):

You download free IP2Location LITE DB1 which is free database for country resolution by IP address http://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country

You can query the database from database servers or using the programming libraries from https://www.ip2location.com/developers